# Move Storage Disk to Another Machine

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have an Ubuntu Server (23.04) set up with two disks: OS on disk1 (/dev/sda) and storage on disk2 (/dev/sdb). Perhaps naively, I thought that moving the storage disk to another machine (also Ubuntu Server 23.04) would be as simple as editing /etc/fstab on the second machine to mount /dev/sdb on a new mount point.

This is the point at which I came unstuck as I realised it is perhaps a more complex task. Could anyone help with the correct procedure to achieve this?

Thanks,
Jamie.

Comment: In your fstab, better to use UUIDs instead of device names, which might change or be different on a different machine with its own devices already using that name.

Comment: With the caveat that @ubfan1 mentions (in your other machine, the drive might not be `/dev/sdb`), this is indeed the procedure to move a drive to another machine. Apart from the physical move, carefully modifying both `/etc/fstab`s is what you need to do.

Comment: Another consideration is the owner/group of the files on the disk being moved may not match or even exist on the new machine.  Either change them as necessary or ensure they match on both machines.

Comment: Excellent!! ..thanks. Using the UUID did the trick.